# Unable to post a nested array inside an array using NodeJS to MongoDB using Angular

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, angular8

This is my Angular TS file:

```
   const salaryInfo = {
    payrollDetails: ( this.payrollDetails)
  } 

  console.log('salaryInfo :', this.payrollDetails );

  this.payrollSalaryService.newSalary(salaryInfo).subscribe(data => {
    if (!data.success) {
      this.messageClass = 'alert alert-danger';
      this.message = data.message; 
      this.processingTransaction = false; 
    } else {
      this.messageClass = 'alert alert-success'; 
      this.message = data.message; 
      this.performAuthentication()
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.processingTransaction = false; 
        this.message = false;
        jQuery("#payrollModal").modal("hide");
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
```

this.payrollDetails is queried from the database. 
When viewed from the browser, it returns a name and a nested array: work[]

My mongoose schema is this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; 
const Schema = mongoose.Schema; 

const payrollSalarySchema = new Schema({
    date: {type: String },
    payrollDetails: [{
        branch: { type: String },
        department: { type: String },
        lastName: { type: String },
        name: { type: String },
        work: [{
            regularWorkHours: { type: Number },
          //  hourlyRate: { type: String },
        //    holidayCredit: { type: String },
        }]
      }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('PayrollSalary', payrollSalarySchema);
```

And my routes file in NodeJS is this:

```
router.post('/newSalary', async (req, res) => {

    console.log('payrollDetails :', req.body.payrollDetails);


    try {
        const payrollSalary = new PayrollSalary({
            date: new Date(),
            payrollDetails: req.body.payrollDetails,
        });
        await payrollSalary.save();
        res.json({ success: true, message: 'Salary Processing Completed.' });
    } catch (err) { res.json({ success: false, message: 'An error occured' }); }
});


module.exports = router;
```

When I console.log('payrollDetails :', req.body.payrollDetails); in the nodejs, the nested array work[] is is empty. However, this is not empty the same is console logged in the browser.

Also, if this.payrollDetails is not queried from a database and I replace it with constant values, the nested array work[] appears.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please go through all these links: [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [how to good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please post the code instead of image

Comment: @kedarsedai I have posted the code now.

Comment: @ngShravil.py I have edited my question, is it sufficient now? would it satisfy your query such that you can help me now?